# Getting error in the first line of YAML file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, yaml

This is my yml script which I want to run to create an ec2 instance. But i'm getting error in the first line no matter what I put in there.

SYNTAX CHECKED AND IS FINE.

error:

```
"ERROR! A malformed block was encountered.

The error appears to have been in '/root/aws-create/ec2c.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

-
  name: Stage instance(s)
  ^ here"
```

```html
-
  name: Stage instance(s)
  hosts: aws
  connection: ssh
  remote_user: ec2-user
  become: yes
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    keypair: newrhel_2
    instance_type: t2.micro
    security_group: default
    image: ami-b55a51cc
    aws_region: us-west-2
    aws_access_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    aws_secret_key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  tasks:
    ec2:
      aws_access_key={{aws_access_key}}
      aws_secret_key={{aws_secret_key}}
      keypair={{keypair}}
      group={{security_group}}
      instance_type={{instance_type}}
      image={{image}}
      region={{aws_region}}
      wait=true
      count=1
```

Comment: What's the single `-` on the first line for?  I've seen three `---` indicating a YAML file, but not one by itself.

Comment: @Jack It indicates a list element - one of the most basic constructs in YAML. And playbooks are lists of plays.

Comment: OK -- I've just never seen one all by itself before.  I'd have `name:` up on the same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tasks` should contain a list, not a dictionary (and because you use Ansible notation, `ec2` is not valid as a YAML dictionary). You need to add a hyphen before `ec2`:

```
tasks:
  - ec2:
```

Comment: thank you so much. I'm a newbie to yaml. You saved my day.